# unstable_getServerSession returning session null and 'decryption operation failed',

Tags: mongodb, session, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to get session as respond to PUT request. But I only get null as respond.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { unstable_getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { initMongoose } from "../../lib/mongoose";
import User from "../../models/User";
import { authOptions } from "./auth/[...nextauth]";

export default async function handle(req, res) {
  await initMongoose();
  const session = await unstable_getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);

  if (req.method === "PUT") {
    const { username } = req.body;
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate();
    res.json(session);
  }

  if (req.method === "GET") {
    const id = req.query.id;
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    res.json({ user });
  }
}
```

[...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter";
import clientPromise from "../../../lib/mongodb";

export const authOptions = {
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/",
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  callbacks: {
    session: async ({ token, session }) => {
      if (session?.user && token?.sub) {
        session.user.id = token.sub;
      }
      
      return session;
    },
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

`

I'm trying to get session as respond to PUT request. But I only get null as respond. this is the git repo link : https://github.com/kusalkalinga00/twitter-clone.